# Android: Layout with row span

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to figure out how to create a layout that looks like this.

```
--------------------------------
Sep Text here
--------------------------------
text 1 here                 | IMG
text 2 Here                 |  
--------------------------------
```

I have tried to do this with a table layout inside of a table layout but than I am having trouble accessing the "text 1" and text 2" to set their values. Any thoughts on how I should accomplish this? Or maybe you can tell me how to access elements that are down two levels of layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished with a RelativeLayout. It would be implemented in the lines of the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Accessing text1 and text2 by code could be done by:

```
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

// set text
text1.setText("foo");
text2.setText("bar");
```

Hope it helps!