# How to divide horizontal view into 3 different layouts in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to make a layout which is divided into 3 parts like this :

[image]

And here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0px"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.system_2.taxiapp.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.30"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="0">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.60"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it correct way to make this or there is a better way ? I am new to android and that's why asking this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

use grid layout with 2 rows and 2 column for that vertical relativelayout use rowspan

you can also have look on it - [Android: Layout with row span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302203/android-layout-with-row-span)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Paste this 
    `

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstLY"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/secondLY">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="FIRST"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLY"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/cornflower_blue_light_40"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstLY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/thirdLY">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="SECOND"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/thirdLY"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/testred"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondLY">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="THIRD"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`